# Cant start Android studio on mac after updating VM options

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm, heap-memory

On Android studio, when running an apk on my device, I started getting java heap size issues. So I updated the VM options of Android studio using help>Edit custom vm options as recommended.
I did a restart and since then I am not able to start my Android studio at all.
How do I go about updating the vm options without IDE so that it can start?

I restarted my mac, but still the same.

What do you recommend?

Prior to the java heap space issue, the apk was running okay on my device.

Answer (score 3):

Find and delete the `studio.exe.vmoptions` file. 
In windows, it was in `C:\Users\UserA\.AndroidStudio2.2\studio.exe.vmoptions`
In Mac, see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924393/6913143)

Comment: Nice suggestion but instead deleting the file. I opened it and undid the changes I made. Sometime there is common error you might have introduced while updating. Fix those typo or error and you will be able to launch it again.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910988/android-studio-wont-start-after-updating-vm-options)

On Mac OS, fastest way: find the vmoptions file and delete/restore it.

```
sudo find / -name studio.vmoptions
```

Android studio will regenerate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value in the system environment variable for _JAVA_OPTIONS. I faced a similar issue since the value for -Xmx was 512m in the environment variable. Increasing it to a higher value (-Xmx8g) in the environment variable resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, this was under `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/<my android studio version>/studio.vmoptions`