# Android studio won't start after updating vm options

Tags: android-studio

I recently installed android studio on a Mactop pro running OSX 10.11. with the standard Apple JRE/JDK.

I had some problems with the slowness of the IDE and the fact that the emulator was hanging. After doing some research I was advised to set VM options as follows -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512 I did this using using Android -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler. This seemed to work ok until I restarted android studio.

Now, every attempt to start android studio now results in this error (from the console log).

> 28/01/2017 14:04:43.617 studio[1003]: allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
>   28/01/2017 14:04:43.628 studio[1003]: fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
>   28/01/2017 14:04:43.629 studio[1003]: fullFileName exists:
>   /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
>   28/01/2017 14:04:43.629 studio[1003]: Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is
>   (null) 28/01/2017 14:04:43.629 studio[1003]: Processing VMOptions file
>   at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
>   28/01/2017 14:04:43.629 studio[1003]: Done 28/01/2017 14:04:43.629
>   studio[1003]: Processing VMOptions file at
>   /Users/lesormonde/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/studio.vmoptions
>   28/01/2017 14:04:43.629 studio[1003]: Done 28/01/2017 14:04:43.629
>   studio[1003]: Processing VMOptions file at  28/01/2017 14:04:43.631
>   studio[1003]: No content found 28/01/2017 14:04:43.637 studio[1003]:
>   JNI_CreateJavaVM (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk)
>   failed: 4294967290

The contents of the file 
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions are

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOopslesormondesMBP2:bin
```

A reinstall of android studio has had no effect. 
I thought to remove any relevant options files, but there are none at ~/Library/Preferences/androidstudio2.2/ which is where the documentation tells you to look and various disk searches haven't produced anything helpful

I am currently dead in the water. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

I found the vmoptions file in ~/Library/preferences/AndroidStudio2.2 
Deleting the vmoptions file resolved the problem. 
Begs the question of why Android Studio allowed me to save options that had that effect.

Comment: yep, that was the issue

Comment: Then where should I write VM options?

Answer (score 5):

The `studio.vmoptions` on AS 4.X is moved to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.X` now. Just revert or remove this file then you can start AS again.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#file_location

Comment: Thank you, good sir. This helped me revert what I did.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration you need to set the environment variable `STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS` to where your `vmoptions` file is located (even though it says you should add the variable if you put your `vmoptions` file elsewhere).

On my windows machine I set the variable to `%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio2.2\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

Answer (score 3):

Was experiencing the same issue, tried followings with no luck:

1. removed and installed new version of Android Studio -> no luck
2. updated java_home and Jdk_home in environment varaible -> no luck
3. updated java version etc ...nothing seemed to work !!!

**Finally** went to `~/Library/preferences/AndroidStudioX.X` and simply removed `studio.vmoptions`

Volla, launched Android studio all fine again

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way: find the vmoptions file and delete/restore it.

```
sudo find / -name studio.vmoptions
```

Or

```
sudo find / -name studio64.vmoptions
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it'll work in all
but,if you can't found that options then you can try this:

Go to the Android studio setup and reinstall it and then delete the older and go to your all applications then you'll see Android studio application is looking new and then try to open and your all projects are there too.